# How to select an option in controller using angular schema form?

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I just want to use code in controller to select an option in [Angular Schema Form](http://schemaform.io) .

I have the following in HTML Markup:

```
<div sf-schema=schema sf-form=form sf-model=formData></div>
```

Now, I want to do this in controller:

```
//controller.js

//This is not working
$scope.formData.select_1 = 4;
$scope.formData.select_2 = 3;

//Schema for the form
$scope.schema = 
    "select_1": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
    },
    "select_2": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
    }
$scope.form = //All the form properties here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your code.

The schema is wrong.

```
$scope.schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
            "select_1": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        },
            "select_2": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        }
    }
}
```

You defined the schema as a string, yet you're setting the value as an int.

```
$scope.formData.select_1 = "4";
$scope.formData.select_2 = "3";
```

Make sure you've defined the model object (formData) before setting values.

```
$scope.formData = {};
```

However, you could have just set the model with the values above.

```
$scope.formData = {select_1: "4", select_2: "3"};
```

Here's a Plunker with the working code.

[Pluner Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6D5Ib9dtvzJGeSKjg49p?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I did get it to work after making the changes you made.